# Capturing Web Pages in Adobe AIR

Tags: air

i am wanting to do a note taking application

alot of times, i will want to capture entire/portions of web pages. can i do it with adobe air? can it integrate with browsers like firefox? if not i will use the browser integrated with AIR. but how can i capture whats on the browser control? it shld be able to capture flash and entire/scrolling web pages.

sometimes i want to tag/comment on certain parts of a web page. is there a way to access the HTML to add additional content in it?

Answer (score 0):

unless you are doing this just for an exercise, you should look at [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/)

Comment: hmm i am doing it more for learning purposes and personal use if its good, so i can say its for exercise, but i do know abt evernote too